# Virustotal видит пустой файл скомпилированный в Pyinstaller'e как вирус

Tags: python, pyinstaller, virustotal

Абсолютно пустой файл test4.py упаковал Pyinstaller'ом и проверил в VirusTotal, в итоге получил 8 дэтектов.
[image: 8 дэтектов]

Также узнал что файл отправлял запросы на разные айпи

[image: Странные айпи запросы]

Где то слышал что Pyinstaller пакует все модули которые видит, проверил модули

[image: мои модули]

упаковывал так

```
pyinstaller test4.py --onefile
```

Как можно отключить эти запросы и почему они вообще происходят, почему VirusTotal видит вирусы когда код пустой? Проблема в Pyinstaller'е, модулях или среде разработки (Pycharm)?

ссылка на проверку файла - https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/0fb03cc5fe146544da09ae703b78c1d426a2d6093a9e0d0a056162ad7e281a83/behavior

Comment: проблема в том, что `pyinstaller`  создает самораспаковывающийся архив. а это по умолчанию - вирус.